# symfony doctrine with two entity managers manually bind select tag

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I googled a lot trying to find an answer for my problem, but no luck.

I have two tables in two different db `db1.pages` and `db2.layouts` I have defined the two entity managers and I can successfully manage the two as unrelated entities.

My problem is on table `db1.pages`, I have a `layout_id` column which contains a reference to the `db2.layouts.id` column, I didn't created an association between the two because, from my understanding, is not supported by doctrine. I successfully managed to display a selection list of possible layouts on the `PageType` using the following code:

```
$builder
  ->add('name', null, array('label' => 'Name'))
  ->add('label', null, array('label' => 'Title'))
  ->add('home', null, array('label' => 'Homepage'))
  ->add('layoutId', 'entity', array(
          'class' => 'USGMCMSBundle:Layouts',
          'property' => 'label',
          'label' => 'Layout',
      ))
```

but it doesn't select the correct layout matched by the value stored into `layoutId`. Is there a way to select the current selected item and keep it in sync when the user choose a different one?

Maybe using an `EventSubscriber`? but on which stage? Or is there a better solution?

Hope I made myself clear (sorry for my english)